# Types of Hadoop Clusters

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have seen heard there are types of clusters: Single Node,Pseudo Distributed and MultiNode.
I would like to know about clear differences among them.
I am new to this field.So please explain clearly.

Comment: This will help you http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hadoop/different-modes-of-hadoop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the components of a [Hadoop cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#NameNode+and+DataNodes):

1. Name node: Hold Meta Data
2. Task Tracker: Accept tasks
3. Job Tracker: Farms out Map reduce tasks
4. Data Node: Holda Data
5. Secondary Name node: Managed edit log of namenode. Don't let the name deceive you, its not a backup/failover.

In a **single node mode**: All components lie on a single machine

In a **multi node mode**: All components are distributed on several machines.

In a **pseudo distributed mode**: The components run on local machine which simulates a small cluster.  HDFS is still used instead of the local filesystem